# Multiple excluding conditions for RewriteCond

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URLs:

- `/a/`
- `/a?b=any-param-value`
- `/any/other/urls/`
- `/any-other-urls?with=any-params`

I want to attach to any url, **but not to** `/a/`, **and not to** `/a?b=any-param-value`, per `X-Robot-Tag` `noindex, nofollow`.

Is this rule correct? Or is there a smarter way?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^b)= [NC]
RewriteCond Request_URI !(*\/a\/*)
RewriteRule .* : [E=DO_SEO_HEADER:1]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=DO_SEO_HEADER
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `mod_rewrite` rules. Just use [`If` expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} !~ /(^|&)b=/ && %{THE_REQUEST} !~ m#/a/#">
   Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</If>
</IfModule>
```